# default variable in bash 3 or bash 4

Tags: bash, shell, variable

I have this:

```
local v="${name-$tag}"  # default is name, tag is backup
```

except it doesn't work if name is empty. So the long-way to do this would be:

```
local v="$name";

if [[ -z "$v" ]]; then
   v = "$tag"
fi
```

is there a shorthand way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The `${variable-alternate value}` construct uses the alternate value if the variable is set, but not if it's set to the empty string (i.e. blank). If you want to use the alternate value if the variable is unset OR set to the empty string, use `${variable:-alternate value}` (note the colon) instead:

```
local v="${name:-$tag}"
```